# Is there anyway to move AWS infrastructure from one region to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, ec2-ami, aws-php-sdk

I have,

- EC2 x 8
- AMIs x 2
- RDS x 1
- ELBs x 2
- SG (security Groups) x 8
- VPCs x 1

in **Tokyo** region. But I would like to move my entire setup to **Oregon**. Is there any tool I can utilise to do this?

By mistake this question has "Move" in it. But I am expecting the tool to do **Replication**.

Answer (score 6):

You can copy AMIs to a different region. But that's pretty much it. You will have to build the whole thing from the ground-up in new region.

You can however, create a Cloud-formation template from your existing set-up, then later edit it to match the region/AZ specific values and then use this template in new region to create stack.

But yeah, again, this is not a **MOVE** operation as you expected. One way or other, you have to build the things in new region.

Comment: end up writing a script which describes all the resource one by one and copies entire infrastructure into second region with configuration. all good thanks mate!

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what exactly you did when you say `copies entire infrastructure into second region` . Thanks.

Comment: So, I am describing each resource from top to bottom fashion. Starting with VPC. By calling describeVPC function from AWSPhpSDK and then use createVPC to create exact configuration from source to destination. Similarly I go thru every single resources and re-create them in destination and hook them up. :)

Comment: Correct. So you are not **MOVING** any thing. Instead you are building everything from the ground up in the new region.

Comment: You are right, my question should be. Is there anyway to replicate the infrastructure :)

Comment: I rejected your edit because then it would make all other answers on this thread look awkward and irrelevant for future user who will read this post. Hope you understand.

Comment: What if in future someone wants to answer a replication solution?

Comment: Raise a new question for replication where you will receive inputs regarding various ways of replication across 2 different regions.

Comment: yep - for what it's worth - i also ended up using CloudFormation to copy resources across. It's still a little buggy, and there were some issues between incompatibilities across zones, but at least I was able to do it all in one day...

Comment: @TeaCupApp can you please share the script, because i do need to replicate my existing whole architecture to stockholm... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to move it.  However, you could use OpWorks to create a CloudFormation script that would allow you to re-create it in another region.

I don't think it will move AMIs, but you can do than manually.